# How to decorate admin actions in Django, action.__name__ used as dict key?

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

In order to avoid duplication, I decided to decorate some actions that I use within Django administration. The decorator is very simple - wraps the function, evaluates it, and in case of `TransitionError` shows the appropriate error message to the user. It also gets the `short_description` and applies it.

```
def transition_action(short_description):
    def decorator(fn):
        def wrapped(modeladmin, request, queryset):
            try:
                return fn(modeladmin, request, queryset)
            except TransitionNotAllowed:
                message = _("Transition not allowed.")
                messages.error(request, message)
        wrapped.short_description = short_description
        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

However, if that decorator is applied, then only the last action will be visible (from all where the decorator is applied). The reason is that the `wrapped.__name__` will be used as key for actions dictionary ([reference](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.17/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L887)).

Obviously, a way to workaround this behavior would be to set custom `__name__`, like that: `wrapped.__name__ = short_description`. I don't like this approach though, as it seems a bit hackish.

Do you have some better approaches to apply decorations to actions?

Comment: You need to use @wraps decorator
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps

Answer (score 1):

I just made it like that:

```
def add_short_description(short_description: str):
    def decorator(admin_action):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return admin_action(*args, **kwargs)
        wrapper.short_description = short_description
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Then in `admin.py`:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    actions = [ ..., 'my_action', ...]

    @add_short_description('Some description')
    def my_action(self, request, queryset):
        ...
```

Comment: In Django 3.2 I've had to extend this so under
wrapper.short_description = short_description
there's
wrapper.__name__ = short_description

Comment: I could not get it working in Django 3.2. @TheMadBug could you provide a full example? 